# PHP Mysql query to output a list in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop

I know the title of my question is maybe a bit stupid but my programming and english skills are literally not the best.

Im trying to echo some Data out of my SQL but one of my queries is always missing some output.

If you look at the table screenshot there shoud be another row in the HTML but it doesnt output.

My question is: where is the bug that the script sometimes does not output all of the data

```
    echo '<ul>';
$bestellangaben = $pdoCon->query("SELECT * FROM `bestellangaben` WHERE SeitenID = $currentSeitenID ORDER BY ID DESC");
$printline = '';
$currentGrouping = -1;
foreach ($bestellangaben as $eintrag) {
    if($currentGrouping == $eintrag['grouping']) {
        $printline = $printline . ' - ' . $eintrag['bestlellangaben'];
    }else{
        if($printline != ''){
            echo '<li>' . $printline . '</li>';
        }
        $printline = $eintrag['bestlellangaben'];
        $currentGrouping = $eintrag['grouping'];
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Table of Data:

[image: The Table]

Output of product 187:

[image: HTML of Product 187]

Comment: Which data do you miss?

Comment: The next row or better said the next list at product 187 the items with the id  113 till 116 is missing

Comment: Its all the output i get.

Comment: I added my solution as an answer

Comment: You really should be using [bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php) with your PDO Database connection, rather than manually inserting variables into your SQL, this is potentially very dangerous.

Comment: Ok thank you! , as you can see im not a good coder :/ 
The system is running on xammp its a one time solution to get the old content of the website for the new website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss to output the last `$printline`. When you reach the last dataset with the same grouping as the previous dataset, there is no output anymore. It just adds the content to `$printline`. You do it as the following:

```
    echo '<ul>';
$bestellangaben = $pdoCon->query("SELECT * FROM `bestellangaben` WHERE SeitenID = $currentSeitenID ORDER BY ID DESC");
$printline = '';
$currentGrouping = -1;
foreach ($bestellangaben as $eintrag) {
    if($currentGrouping == $eintrag['grouping']) {
        $printline = $printline . ' - ' . $eintrag['bestlellangaben'];
    }else{
        if($printline != ''){
            echo '<li>' . $printline . '</li>';
        }
        $printline = $eintrag['bestlellangaben'];
        $currentGrouping = $eintrag['grouping'];
    }
}

if($printline != ''){
    echo '<li>' . $printline . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank your really really much!

Sitting on this issue allready 6 hours...

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow i didnt knew how sry